# Formatting support for \[LeftDoubleBracket] and \[RightDoubleBracket]

Tags: feature-request, design

It has become common practice on Mathematica.SE to us the Unicode characters for a number of *Mathematica* symbols.  This works because these are correctly interpreted when copied and pasted into a Notebook.

*Mathematica* provides double-bracket characters for `Part` application.  These can greatly improve legibility of code with lots of square brackets, but attempting to use them in posts reveals a problem.

This code:    `list[[Ordering[set[[All, 1]], 15]]]`

With `\[LeftDoubleBracket]` and `\[RightDoubleBracket]` should look like:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But instead it looks like this, with an extra space to the outside of these brackets, and the brackets are not vertically aligned:

`list〚Ordering[set〚All, 1〛, 15]〛`

There is however another pair of Unicode characters that have the correct appearance but unfortunately *Mathematica* does not interpret these correctly, so copy and paste of this line will fail:

`list⟦Ordering[set⟦All, 1⟧, 15]⟧`

I am requesting a formatting change, if it is possible, such that the upper line of code is rendered in appearance as the lower line.

Conceivably this could be done by either:

- Changing the display kerning of the Unicode `U+301A` and `U+301B` characters to behave as single-width characters without the space, and correct alignment, possibly using the syntax highlighter script.
- Replacing these characters with `U+27E6` and `U+27E7` for display, but somehow using `U+301A` and `U+301B` when the code is copied.

If either of these is possible I am requesting that it be done.

Comment: Copy+paste is probably the main reason this is not such a good idea.

Comment: @David what do you mean?  As I said in the second bullet point it would be necessary for this to copy correctly; that's the whole point of this request, otherwise one could use `U+27E6` and `U+27E7` right now (but it would break copy & paste).

Comment: it is possible using javascript, but SE will have philosophical issues with a code block (which is supposed to be verbatim) not _really_ being what it purports to be. Besides, these are font and OS dependent and the latter set of characters (U+27E6 and U+27E7) are not the same height as a square bracket on my machine and that is very jarring. Nevertheless, if they're willing to fix the kerning and implement it, I do agree it will be useful.